# How do I copy a database from one MongoDB server to another?

Tags: mongodb

I have two mongodbs in different server, both start with `--auth`. Now I want to copy a db from one server to another.

```
> mongo
> use admin
> db.copyDatabase("mydb","mydb","another_server")
```

It shows:

```
{ "errmsg" : "", "ok" : 0 }
```

And:

```
> db.getLastError()
null
```

Seems no error, but the copy is not successful. What's the correct command to use?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If you are using **--auth**, you'll need to include your username/password in there...

Also you *must* be on the "destination" server when you run the command.

```
db.copyDatabase(<from_db>, <to_db>, <from_hostname>, <username>, <password>);
```

If all that doesn't work, you might want to try something like creating a slave of the database you want to copy ...

Comment: The username and password mentioned is for database not for host name
PS: I made this mistake hence mentioning it :)

Comment: Thank you! That was super simple. For my case I did not have a username or pass so I had to leave those parameters off.

Comment: can't i somehow copy the data base into mongo's datafolder ?

Comment: @eranotzap you can shutdown one database, copy the datafiles and transfer them to another server (which you also probably want to shutdown first) but in my opinion it's not only much easier much easier to use copyDatabase (no shutdown/file copy/transfer needed) ... but it's also a lot safer as it works more like replication to a slave.

Comment: thanks. @JustinJenkins
Sometimes the db is very large how do i know which files belong to which db ?

Comment: am getting below error **{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "not master", "code" : 10107 }** . command used `db.copyDatabase('qa_db','qa_db','10.xx.xx.xxx')` . I am not using auth hence not using username/pwd options

Comment: db.copyDatabase is deprecated for the version > 4.0.  Does any know how to copy db from a server to server for the version > 4.0 ?

Comment: @BSM https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#mongodump-example-copy-clone-database

Comment: Getting `WARNING: db.copyDatabase will only function with MongoDB 4.0 and below. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.2-copydb-clone`

Comment: Starting in version 4.2, MongoDB removes the deprecated copydb command and clone command.

Comment: the documentation says: from version 4.2 use mongodump: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#copy-and-clone-databases

Answer (score 52):

Starting from `Mongo` version `3.2` you  can  do  it  by  using `mongodump/mongorestore`:

```
mongodump  --host <from_host> --db <from_db> --archive | mongorestore --host <to_host> --archive
```

Additional info could be found at:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/

To make remote mongo reachable you can create ssh tunnel  to  it:

creates a tunnel to the remote mongodb server and tunnels it through port 27117 to the local client

```
ssh -fN -L 27117:localhost:27017 <remote_host>
```

In this case the command to run on the local machine you want to restore to could be:

```
mongodump  --port 27117 --db <from_db> --archive | mongorestore --archive
```

Answer (score 24):

In addition to the answer of Justin Jenkins keep in mind that you also can use a ssh tunnel if you don't have mongodb exposed to the network (localhost only)

I use screen to switch between "tasks". for my convenience the ssh tunnel and mongo are executed in separate screen tabs.

step 1: create a tunnel

```
ssh username@yourdomainOrIP -L 27018:localhost:27017
...Enter your password
```

step 2 :

```
mongo
use admin
db.copyDatabase(<fromdb>,<todb>,"localhost:27018",<username>,<password)
```

Comment: Just to clarify these instructions a bit for those who have never created an SSH tunnel before: 27018 here is an arbitrary local port that is not used.  To ensure it is not used, use "lsof -ti:9000".  If processes are returned, use lsof to find an unused port.  The second 27017 port in this answer is the port mongo is running on, on the remote host you are copying from.  To ensure this is correct, sign in to the remote host and confirm mongo is running on this port with: "lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep mongo".

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the answer of Mike Shauneu, if your database name on the destination server is not the same as on the source server you need to rewrite the namespace. In combination with authentication I got this to work using the `--uri` option, which requires a recent mongo version (>3.4.6):

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://$sourceUser:$sourcePwd@$sourceHost/$sourceDb" --gzip --archive | mongorestore --uri="mongodb://$targetUser:$targetPwd@$targetHost/$targetDb" --nsFrom="$sourceDb.*" --nsTo="$targetDb.*" --gzip --archive
```

Comment: This is currently the most flexible and accurate answer (see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#copy-clone-a-database), also because the `--db` option is now deprecated

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me to copy from Ubuntu Server to another Ubuntu Server, both running MongoDB v4+:

1. The following command should be executed from the server, where you want to restore the database:

```
   ssh -fN -L 27018:127.0.0.1:27017 <remote_host_ip>
```

2. Now we have mapped our remote server database to our local server port 27018. Next, we can copy from remote server to our destination server using MongoDB's `mongodump/mongorestore` pipeline:

```
   mongodump --port 27018 --db <remote_db_name> --username <remote_db_username> --password <remote_db_password> --archive | mongorestore --username <destination_db_username> --password <destination_db_password> --archive
```

3. [OPTIONAL] You can check your restored database as followings:

```
   mongo --authenticationDatabase "admin" -u <destination_db_username> -p
```

```
   show dbs
```

Check if your database exists in the list.

Comment: This is actually a clever trick, piping a dump to a restore. Tho it works with small dbs otherwise you need a pretty solid connection, any broken connection will make the restoration fail.