# How can I transfer a mongodb database to another machine that cannot see the first one

Tags: mongodb, copy, database

I have a server that is having trouble talking to the outside world.  I would like to get its mongodb contents to another server--but since the servers cannot talk to eachother [db.copyDatabase()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495137/how-do-i-copy-a-database-from-one-mongodb-server-to-another) won't do.

Is there something like mysqldump where I could dump the db into a binary file, scp that somewhere, and then use that to populate another mongodb server?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the [mongodump and mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) commands.

```
mongodump --db test --collection collection
mongorestore --collection collection --db test dump/
```

You can also gzip. The documentation has more examples.

Comment: mongodump--so obvious in hindsight.

Comment: Does this work for old versions? I have mongo v2.4.9 and it says: ` mongodump is not defined`.

Comment: i know this but if my data is huge with many collection now can i copy and paste whole database from file manager to another PC?

Comment: I meet some pb with the mongorestore (`root directory must be a dump of a single database`) I use : `mongorestore  --db myDB .\dump\myDB` as you can read in [Mongodb monogorestore “root directory must be a dump of a single database”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27923656/608772) or here under

Answer (score 38):

If you're using Ubuntu/Linux, run the following commands. First, `mongodump` on the origin server:

```
mongodump --db DataBaseName
```

Copy the generated `dump/DataBaseName` folder to the new machine. Then, import using `mongorestore`:

```
mongorestore --db DataBaseName /path/to/DataBaseName
```

Note that `/path/to/DataBaseName` should be a directory filled with .json and .bson representations of your data.

Comment: To save to a specific location add --out like: mongodump --db DataBaseName --out ~/backups/

Answer (score 4):

If you want to transfer database to another system, then you must use the following commands.

First dump the database to the output directory:

```
mongodump --db DatabaseName -o ./DirectoryName
```

then copy that directory and put it into your machine and issue this command:

```
mongorestore --db DBName ./DirectoryName
```