# Mongodb monogorestore "root directory must be a dump of a single database"

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I'm trying to restore a mongodump to a differently named database (which should be possible via `--db <dbname>` switch).

*My working directory contains a single dump folder, which contains a single db dump.*

However, when I try this command:

```
mongorestore --port xxxxx --db some_destination_db
```

I get the following error:

```
 ERROR: ERROR: root directory must be a dump of a single database
 ERROR:        when specifying a db name with --db
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this, and can't find any help on google.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I think in the directory where you are applying the mongorestore command has dumps more than one database. Try performing the dump command again to a new empty directory, and then import.

Comment: @LeonardoDelfino - definately only one db in the dump directory.  I created the dump with mongodump --db xxx which specifies a single db to process.  Have also verified manually - only one subfolder in the dump directory (named same as db).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to include the path of the source db dump directory to restore from (as at MongoDB 2.6).

For example, if restoring from "twitter" to "some_destination_db" your command line would be similar to:

> mongorestore --port xxxxx --db some_destination_db dump/twitter

Answer (score 0):

May be your destination path contains some subfolders