# Why are only empty rows copied when copying db from different server?

Tags: mongodb

Getting my head around mongo atm. I am trying to copy a complete database from a server to my pc:

```
db.copyDatabase(fromdb, todb, fromhost)
```

The fromHost db contains 4 collections with rows in it. For some reason the local version of this db has all the collections but are empty:

```
db1 0.000GB
db2 0.000GB
```

What am I missing why are the rows empty?

Answer (score 0):

Q: Why are the rows empty?

A: It looks like something went wrong.

If you haven't already, I would try `db.getLastError()` to see if there's any error message.

I would also look at this link:

> [How do I copy a database from one MongoDB server to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495137/how-do-i-copy-a-database-from-one-mongodb-server-to-another)
>
> If you are using `--auth`, you'll need to include your username/password
>   in there...
>
> Also you must be on the "destination" server when you run the command.
>
> `db.copyDatabase(<from_db>, <to_db>, <from_hostname>, <username>,
>   <password>);`
>
> If all that doesn't work, you might want to try something like
>   creating a slave of the database you want to copy ...

Finally, review the materials on the MongoDb "copyDatabase" man page:

- https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/

Please post back with any additional details (e.g. error message).

And, if you get it working, please post back what was wrong, and how you fixed it!

Good luck!